# OkHttp 3.11 and TLS 1.2 support

Tags: java, android, tls1.2, okhttp

The support for TLS v1.2 was added in Android 4.2, but it wasn't enabled by default. This issue was quite easy to fix with OkHttp 3.x by providing a [custom SSLSocketFactory implementation](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1934) to the OkHttp client:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setSocketFactory(new MySSLSocketFactory());
```

In my case the custom socket factory was setting the enabled protocols like this:

```
private static final String[] TLS_PROTOCOLS = new String[]{ "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2" };

public MySSLSocketFactory(final KeyManager[] keyManagers, final TrustManager trustManager) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
  final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(TLS);
  sslContext.init(keyManagers, new TrustManager[]{ trustManager }, null);
  // ...
}

// ...

private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(final Socket socket) {
  if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
    ((SSLSocket) socket).setEnabledProtocols(TLS_PROTOCOLS);
  }
  return socket;
}
```

In the latest OkHttp 3.11 we can read

> Fix: Prefer TLSv1.2 where it is available. On certain older platforms
>   it is necessary to opt-in to TLSv1.2

I was trying to check relevant commits (probably [this one](https://github.com/square/okhttp/commit/bdbe2dad8806a77bf018b87f4518df250fa67f89)) but I'm not sure if it addresses the same issue as the custom factory does.

So my question is: **is it safe to remove custom SSLSocketFactory when OkHttp 3.11+ is used to keep TSL 1.2 usage on old Android devices?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested the latest (3.11) OkHttp version with default socket factory

`final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(TLS);
sslContext.init(keyManagers, new TrustManager[]{ trustManager }, null);
sslContext.getSocketFactory();`

Unfortunately, TLSv1.2 isn't preferred even though it is available. For now, I have to keep using my own implementation of SSLSocketFactory which includes TLSv1.2.